# Strings, gets and do while

Tags: c, string, gets, openvms

I'm doing an exercise in C but I have a problem when at the and I want to repeat the cicle (do while), infact if I type 1 the programme starts again by the top, but it doesn't stop at the `gets(testo);` . I tried plenty of ways to solve the bug without a solution, can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
        int cch, cw, i, j, w, ord, f; //counter and index
        char testo[80];
        char alfa[50][25];
        char swap[25];

        do{     
                cch=0;
                cw=0;
                j=0;
                w=0;
                f=0;

                for(i=0;i<80;i++){
                        testo[i]='\0';
                }
                printf("Write the text:\n");
                gets(testo);

                //initialization 2d array
                for(i=0;i<50;i++){
                        for(j=0;j<25;j++){
                                alfa[i][j]='\0';
                        }
                }

                j=0;
                //Count word and characters
                if(testo[0]!='\0'){
                        cw=1;   
                        for(i=0;testo[i]!='\0';i++){
                                cch++;
                                if(testo[i]==' '){
                                        cw++;
                                        j++;
                                }
                        }
                }

                if(cch==j){
                        printf("You haven't written any word\n\n");
                }
                else{
                        //Don't count double space
                        for(i=0;i<cch;i++){
                                if(testo[i]==' ' && testo[i+1]==' '){
                                        cw--;
                                }
                        }

                        //Don't count as word if the text start with a space
                        if(testo[0]==' '){
                                cw--;
                                w--;
                        }

                        printf("\nThe text is composed by %d characters\n", cch);
                        printf("The text is composed by %d words\n", cw);

                        if(cw>0){
                                printf("\nUsed words:\n");
                                for(j=0;j<cch;j++){
                                        if(testo[j]==' ' && testo[j+1]==' '){
                                                //nothing to do        
                                        }
                                        else{
                                                if(testo[j]!=' '){
                                                        alfa[w][f]=testo[j];
                                                        f++;
                                                }
                                                else if(testo[j]=='\0'){
                                                        alfa[w][f]='\0';
                                                        f=0;
                                                        w=0;
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                        alfa[w][f]='\0';
                                                        w++;
                                                        f=0;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }

                                for(i=0;i<cw;i++){
                                        printf("%d> %s\n", i+1, &alfa[i]);
                                }

                                //order
                                f=1;
                                printf("\nWords used in alphabetical order:\n");
                                while(f==1){
                                        f=0;
                                        for(i=0;i<cw-1;i++){
                                                ord=strcmp(alfa[i],alfa[i+1]);
                                                if(ord>0){
                                                strcpy(swap,alfa[i]);
                                                strcpy(alfa[i],alfa[i+1]);
                                                strcpy(alfa[i+1],swap);
                                                f=1;
                                                }       
                                        }
                                }

                                for(i=0;i<cw;i++){
                                        printf("%d> %s\n", i+1, alfa[i]);
                                }
                        }
                }

        printf("\nDo you want write another text? (1=yes) -> ");
        scanf("%d", &j);

        }while(j==1);
}
```

I know that isn't very optimized as code at the moment and has other errors, but I'm having problem on this.

Thank you.

PS: The code is tested on OpenVMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and most obvious problem is with the left over newline. When you use `scanf()` here:

```
    printf("\nDo you want write another text? (1=yes) -> ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
}
```

and you use the `%d` format specificer, the function is looking for a number, when you enter a number really you're entering a number and a newline character

```
> 1<enter key>   // which means on stdin you're getting   '1''\n'
```

`scanf()` only picks up the 1 and leaves the newline which your `gets()` function then picks up, so it looks like it's skipping the input. All you need to do is consume that newline character, one quick fix would be to consume it with `getchar()`:

```
    printf("\nDo you want write another text? (1=yes) -> ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    getchar();
}
```

Now your program works as you'd expect.

---

Other issues of note:

1. Your main should really be returning an `int` type, even if it's just a `return 0`
2. You shouldn't be using `gets()`, even then [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets) for `gets()` says **Never use gets().** That's usually a good indication not to. ;)  So replace that line with `fgets(testo, sizeof(testo), stdin);`
3. You missed a performance specificer here: `printf("\nThe text is composed by % characters\n", cch);` so you're getting garbage output, that should have been `%d`

Comment: Thank you, I' m going to try. For the third point I forget to put %d during the translation ;)

Comment: @AlessioMTX - Yes, I assumed the missing `%d` was something forgot in translation, seems to obvious to be missed. Good luck getting it working, let me know if you have any follow up questions. Ciao.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `scanf` call at the end of the loop doesn't read the newline. Instead this newline is read by your `gets` call.

A simple solution is to add a space to the end of the `scanf` format string, like so:

```
scanf("%d ", &j);
```

This will make `scanf` skip trailing whitespace in the input.

Another solution is to put an extra `fgets` after the `scanf`, but then don't add the extra space in the format string:

```
scanf("%d", &j);
fgets(testo, sizeof(testo), stdin);
```

Or use `fgets` to get the line, and then use `sscanf` to extract the answer:

```
fgets(testo, sizeof(testo), stdin);
sscanf(testo, "%d", &j);
```

Comment: If I put the space, when I execute the programme everything Ok, but after that I type 1 e give enter, Write the text isn't shown.

Comment: And If I type 2 after I have to give enter again (twice)

Comment: @AlessioMTX I'm not sure I follow what you mean?

Comment: To exit from the programme I must type a number different from 1, so I type 2, the I press enter but I must type two times to terminate the programme

Comment: Now with I tried with sscanf(testo, "%d", &j); (that I'd never used) but now the programme if I type a number different from 1 terminates easily and correctly, but if I type 1 I can't write the text, I've already the message You haven't witten any word

Comment: @AlessioMTX If you don't use the solutions provided in my answer, the `gets` at the top of the loop will read the remaining newline in the buffer. I suggest you run your program in the debugger, and step through the code line by line while watching e.g. the variables `j` and `testo`.

Comment: ok I'll try with debug, however, now to do a test I put gets(testo); twice, the first time of the loop I must write twice, instead the second time (second loop) only once

Comment: I was going to upvote, but then I saw you proposed not one, but two solutions that use `gets`... :|

Comment: @netcoder I knew it would come back and bind me in the... back.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's exactly what `gets()` does to people, and why it must be avoided. ;-)

Comment: So is better don t use gets?? What should I use? Now I m a bit confused

Comment: @AlessioMTX If you see my updated answer, you see what you should be using instead. `fgets` works almost like `gets`, but is safer. The "almost" part is that `fgets` puts the newline into the buffer, while `gets` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try using the function **flushall()** just before gets()

Comment: flushall gives me error: In this statement, the identifier "flushall" is implicitly declared as a function. Have I to use/add another header file?

Comment: Um no.. It works well with TC and VS. I'm not sure about OpenVMS

Comment: Now I search something similar to use on OpenVMS