# How many chars have the longest word in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have function, which should count how many characters have the longest word, but it counts wrong.

For example, if I enter two words when first one is shorter than second one: "my name" program shows me that the longest word has 2 chars. But when i enter "name my" it shows that the result is 4.  why is that ?

```
void max_chars(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while (sPtr->next != NULL) {
        if (isalpha(sPtr->data)) {
            i++;
        } else {
            if (i > max) {
                max = i;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
        sPtr = sPtr->next;
    }

    printf(" \n The Longest word have : %d chars \n", max);
}
```

Comment: Is `sPtr=sPtr->next` incrementing something? I mention it because you call it twice per loop. One in the while statement, once in the body of the loop. If it is incrementing some pointer, then you go two by two characters. Try printing the currently evaluated character to see what's happening.

Comment: Instead of use NULL use '\0' (standard)

Comment: And look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340343/strings-gets-and-do-while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `my name` when you reach the node `e` you `break` the loop since the `next` is `null` and so the `max` is not updated.
You should update `max` outside of the loop as well or change the condition of the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
void max_chars(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{
    int i = 0;
    int imax = 0;

    for( ;sPtr; sPtr = sPtr->next;) {
        if (isalpha(sPtr->data)) { if(++i > imax) imax=i; }
        else { i = 0;  }
    }

    printf(" \n The Longest word have : %d chars \n", imax);
}
```