# Program doesn't wait for the second read

Tags: c, fgets, getchar

This is a part of a bigger program, but what is driving me crazy is the fact that the program doesn't wait for something to be read from stdin in the string  s (it just puts null in string s) , but if I put the read of the string s first and afterwards I read the character c the program works just fine. The thing is I need to read the data in this specific order.
How can i fix it?

```
char s[100],c;
printf("enter character:\n");
c=getchar();
printf("enter string text:\n");
fgets(s,101,stdin);   
uint8_t s_len = strlen(s) - 1;        
s[s_len] = '\0'; 
printf("i have read %s\n",s);
```

Comment: I had the same problem, here I've solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340343/strings-gets-and-do-while

Comment: Why do you think you can read 101 bytes into a 100 char array? You should use `sizeof s` instead of a hard-coded 101. Another bug: getchar() returns int, not char. And s_len should be a size_t, not a uint8_t.

Comment: @Jens It's fine to store the result of `getchar` in a `char` if you don't want to check for EOF.

Comment: @teppic No, it's not fine. It's a bug. You would misinterpret EOF as a (char)-1 since you can't distinguish them anymore.

Comment: @Jens - I said if you _don't_ check for EOF. The C99 standard itself has an example of `getchar` being assigned to a `char`.

Comment: @teppic Are you referring to Ex. 7 in 5.1.2.3? This is about order of evaluation, not about use of getchar(). Apart from that, I consider that example a bug in C99 promoting sloppy use of getchar. Any code that does not check getchar() for EOF to determine EOF or read failure is buggy. If you *don't* check, you soldier on with a "character" that was never there when you hit EOF or read error. But you can call me a purist :-)

Comment: @Jens - I agree that it's likely a bug, but it's not if you don't care about EOF. One reason to do it is if you're reading from a memory stream which you know is larger than the amount you're reading. I'm not saying it's good style, just not universally incorrect.

Comment: @teppic Fair enough. You got me thinking. Can you point to a source that demonstrates how to use getchar() with a memory stream?

Comment: @Jens: Sure, I just wrote this quick example: http://ideone.com/4Q2L0I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press the enter key for the first character, the actual newline is still left in the input buffer. This newline is then read by the `fgets` call.

You can solve this by a couple if different methods. The first is to add a dummy `getchar` call, to get the newline. This has the drawback that if you're on Windows that newline is actually two characters.

Another solution is to use `fgets` for the first character as well, and then use e.g. `sscanf` to extract the character.

Comment: Thank you.I didn't know that the newline is still left in the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
c = getchar();
int eatMe;
do 
{
   eatMe = getchar();
} while (eatMe != '\n' && eatMe != EOF);
```

Comment: @teppic yep, but from ironFlower's code he/she doesn't need _really_ the value of c :) hence this plausible (if he/she needs the value of c he/she can call to multiple getchar() or use the more elegant fgets)

Comment: It won't work because c is a `char` but must be `int` to hold `EOF`. I strongly recommend reading the comp.lang.c FAQ.

Comment: Edited my post based on the valuable feedback from Jens and ironflower needs :)